# Triggering event on connection errors Javascript chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am building a chrome extension where it detects keys pressed on the keyboard, this is how my content script looks like:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown',function (evt) {
evt = evt || window.event;
var HKdetect='';    
if ("key" in evt) {
    if (evt.key === "Escape" || evt.key === "Esc") {
        HKdetect = 'esc';
    } else if (evt.key === "Space" || evt.key === " ") {
        HKdetect = 'spc';
    }
}

if (HKdetect != '') {            
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ hkpressed: HKdetect, actvURL: location.href }, function (response) {
    });
}
});
```

This code works fine as long as the page does not error out, for example the `keydown` event is not firing when I get a connection error (i.e. invalid SSL certificate).

My guess is that window.onkeydown is only triggered after the connection is successfully established with the server.

Ideally there will be a way to detect websocket errors from chrome extension (content page, or background page), but I could not find out how to listen to events of existing websocket (not events of a newly created websocket).

Any help is much appreciated on how to detect key presses when there is connection error to the page.